# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null with InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Tags: angular, observable

today I met a problem with details component in my private angular application. All I want to archive is get details of customer object with observable usage and after all, pass them to HTML component.

Customer-single.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer-single',
  templateUrl: './customer-single.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-single.component.css']
})
export class CustomerSingleComponent implements OnInit {

  customer$: Observable<CustomerDetails>;

  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.customerService.getOne(id).subscribe(
      data => console.log(this.customer$ = data),
      error => console.error(error.message));
  }

}
```

Customer-single.component.html

```
<p>
  {{(this.customer$ | async).name}}
</p>
<p>
  {{(this.customer$ | async).email}}
</p>
```

After details button click in the main customer component:

```
<div>
  <h1 class="text-primary h1 my-5">Customers list below:</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <table class="table table-striped table-primary">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">No.</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Surname</th>
      <th scope="col">Phone number</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let customer of ( customers$ | async ); let i = index">
      <td scope="row">{{i + 1}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.surname}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.phoneNumber}}</td>
      <td>{{customer.email}}</td>
      <td>
        <a [routerLink]="['/companies/modify', customer.id]" class="btn btn-info mr-2">Modify</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['./single', this.customer.id]" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2">Details</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger mr-2" (click)="onRemove(company.id)">Remove</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" routerLink="add">Add new customer</a>
</div>
```

I am receiving two errors:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

and

```
InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
```

Above I logged a process of assigning values to customer$ observable and required parameter `name` is not null.

I realize that it passes to the details component the same parameter that I display in the main component, but this is only an illustrative example.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the below code :

```
const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
this.customerService.getOne(id).subscribe(
data => console.log(this.customer$ = data),
error => console.error(error.message));
```

To this:

```
const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
this.customerService.getOne(id).subscribe(
data => { 
    console.log(data);
    this.customer$ = data
},
error => {
    console.error(error.message);
});
```

The above code has a subscription and it'll waiting for a result;

So in your template is not necessary to use the pipe async:

Try to change it for this:

```
<p>
{{customer$?.name}}
</p>
<p>
{{customer$?.email}}
</p>
```

good luck

Comment: Awesome, Your solution works, but I would like to specify one issue, namely, after applying your solution my IDE(IntelliJ) in customer-single-component.html marks the name and email in red. I understand that I can ignore it because the new solution works, but I would like to ask if it is syntax-based and couldn't be changed to avoid this highly visible marking on the IDE side?

Comment: Maybe your IDE is warning you that it's necessary to add an interface to access to the keys (name and email) so you can declare an interface for deleting this mark.

Add this before you class or in another file:

export interface CustomerInterface {
    name: string;
    email: string;
}

replace your variable declaration of customer$ for this;

`$customer: PersonInterface;`

Comment: Indeed, this option gave IDE opportunity to recognize name and email without red highlight but I had to remove Observable type from. Is there a chance to keep observable? I want to know that for future potential usage. Thanks for your commitment.

Comment: Surprisingly, the problem was the fact that the HTML component was trying to get information about the field which was currently not available due to the backend delay. The solution was adding keyword else to prevent this situation and in case that we are waiting for backend data display subsidiary component which inform us that we are waiting for data.
Solution below:


`<div *ngIf="(this.customer$ | async) as customer; else loading">
  {{customer.name}}
</div>`


And loading component:


`<ng-template #loading>
  Loading stuff in ngIf...
</ng-template>`